# unable to save hashed password in django

Tags: python, django

hope so y'all are well, so yesterday I was trying to save hashed password in Django, but I was getting a TypeError saying `Password must be a string or bytes, got DeferredAttribute.` I don't know why this isn't working and many people making tutorials on youtube have done it, and they didn't get any errors like this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code snippet containing the password saving code from `views.py` ->

```
def registered(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        customer_email=request.POST.get('email')
        customer_password=request.POST.get('password')
        customer_address=request.POST.get('address')
        register=person(customer_email=customer_email,customer_password=customer_password,   customer_a>
        person.customer_password = make_password(person.customer_password)
        #set_password(customer_password)
        register.save()
 
    return render(request, 'registerednow.html')
```

and here is my `models.py` ->

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class person(models.Model):
    customer_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, primary_key=True)
    customer_password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    customer_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the _full_ error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few things wrong. Try this:

```py
def registered(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        customer_email = request.POST.get('email')
        customer_password = request.POST.get('password')
        customer_address = request.POST.get('address')
        register = person(
            customer_email=customer_email,
            customer_address=customer_address
        )
        register.customer_password = make_password(customer_password)
        register.save()
 
    return render(request, 'registerednow.html')
```